# No matter what I try, I get "App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure."

Tags: ios, http, ssl, alamofire

I'm trying to make a alamofire GET request to my personal website, but I do not have ssl yet. I tried adding the following lines of code to info.plist and STILL no luck:

1) disabling it completely

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
 <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

2) allowing my personal url

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

but I keep getting the same error...

```
2016-03-19 13:02:07.770 appName[51705:9917289] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
[Request]: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7fcc92032140> { URL: http://www.myurl.com/sup?geoSearchWord=test }
[Response]: nil
[Data]: 0 bytes
[Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection."
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5.2:**
You need add a dictionary to your info.plist called "App Transport Security Settings" and in it add a key called "Allow Arbitrary Loads" with the value "YES" 
like so:
[image: info.plist]

Comment: Just not working, don't know the reason why. But doing this same thing for quite a while, worked before.

Answer (score 3):

The first solution should work. Make sure you put that code in your `Info.plist` under the first `<dict>` tag. Also make sure that the plist that you change is the one used in the project settings `Build settings -> Info.plist file`.

Comment: I mean I think it's in the right place. It's the only info.plist in the directory. ACtually you know what, when I'm looking throug "Build Settings", I don't see a category that says info.plist. But I did most definitely put the tags in the right spot inside the file. Because I see it make the change in xcode. It's under Information Property List -> App Transport Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads (boolean YES).

is there maybe something else I can do or some kind of test I can run to make sure it's reading the file in the first place?

Comment: You know what. i bet the file Info.plist isn't even being read properly. I had to copy and paste a lot of files over because of an issue with a back up. So... I guess how do I make a new info.plist, can I have xcode generate one?

Comment: You can make a new plist by right clicking the root folder and `new file -> resources` but it will be empty. You can create a new project and copy it from there, but if you can see it as property list not only as XML probably the file is correct. You should put the name of you plist in `Build settings->Packaging->Info.plist File`

Comment: thx for adding correct pointer to Info.plist  , stucked with this issue since long usually beginner get stuked

Comment: If anyone else fetches up here, I tried all this with it not working. I finally closed down VS, removed app from device and reopend and it worked. Don't know why but somehow perhaps info.plist is retained. Using VS on PC for dev linked to iPhone device via mac so perhaps not sent to mac without full closedown and restart.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` key to YES under the `NSAppTransportSecurity` dictionary in your .plist file.

[image: NSAllowArbitraryLoads]

Answer (score 0):

[image: You have to set like this]

You have to add Allow Arbitrary loads Key and YES value in info plist.